# Can I update the iCloud password from a terminal?

Tags: terminal, icloud, password

I have several Macs in a different country, and I would like to update their iCloud password remotely. I can login to the machines via SSH, but the firewall does not allow me to use VNC.

I would like to know how to update iCloud password using only terminal commands. Is there any way?

Answer (score -1):

check out the "security" command . it my work.

Comment: Thanks. I have already read the man page, but I could not figure out how to do it.